# cat error in shell

Tags: shell-script, cat, here-document

I am using the following code to write files iteratively in 20 folders for job scheduling.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}
do
        cd conf$i
        cp ../nvt.mdp $PWD
        cp ../topol.top $PWD
        grompp -v -f nvt.mdp -c conf$i.gro -p topol.top -o conf_nvt$i.tpr >> nvt.log
        cat<<KHIK >> run_nvt$i.pbs
        #!/bin/bash
        #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
        #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
        #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
        #PBS -q blaze
        #PBS -j oe
        #PBS -V
        cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR
        export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
        /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm conf_nvt$i
        KHIK
        cd ..
done
```

And it is giving out a bizarre error. Can you please tell me what changes I need to make?

```
./umbrnvt.sh: line 22: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `KHIK')
./umbrnvt.sh: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have the close token at the begin of line. So your script should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}
do
        cd conf$i
        cp ../nvt.mdp $PWD
        cp ../topol.top $PWD
        grompp -v -f nvt.mdp -c conf$i.gro -p topol.top -o conf_nvt$i.tpr >> nvt.log
        cat<<KHIK >> run_nvt$i.pbs
        #!/bin/bash
        #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
        #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
        #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
        #PBS -q blaze
        #PBS -j oe
        #PBS -V
        cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR
        export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
        /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm conf_nvt$i
KHIK
        cd ..   
done
```

Otherwise bash will not recognise KHIK as end of the block

Comment: @SouparnoAdhikary, if you find this answer as helpful feel free to upvode and/or mark it as complete answer :)

Comment: @SouparnoAdhikary i.e. click the tick on the left of the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since nobody else has mentioned this,
the error has nothing to do with `cat`. 
You would have the same error with any program,
such as `nl`, `od`, `tr`, or even a non-existent command
like <s>`dog`</s> <s>`unicorn`</s> `tribble`<sup>1</sup>.

The real answer is that you should say `<<-` instead of `<<`. 
As [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354499/80216#354500) almost (but not quite) says, the problem is that,
when you use `<<`,
the shell looks for the delimiter word (`KHIK` in your example)
to be the only thing on the line that terminates the “here document”. 
It can’t be `FOOKHIKBAR`, `FOO KHIK BAR`, `KHIK FU`,
or even `TabKHIK`. 
When you use `<<-`, the shell removes all tab(s)
from the beginning of every line in the here document,
so `TabKHIK` looks like just plain `KHIK`.

But an equally important issue is that, if you say

```
        cat<<KHIK >> run_nvt$i.pbs
        #!/bin/bash
        #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
        #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
        #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
        #PBS -q blaze
        #PBS -j oe
        #PBS -V
        cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR
        export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
        /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm conf_nvt$i
KHIK
```

then you will get

```
        #!/bin/bash
        #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
        #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
        #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
        #PBS -q blaze
        #PBS -j oe
        #PBS -V
        cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
        export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
        /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm conf_nvt{value of $i}
```

in `run_nvt$i.pbs`. 
And that’s not good. 
For a “shebang” (`#!` line) to work correctly,
the `#!` must be the first two characters in the line. 
If you follow the advice of the other answer,
your `run_nvt$i.pbs` script will have a shebang
that is not honored / recognized,
and it might run with `/bin/sh` or some other shell (other than `bash`) —
see [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/502984/354511#503009) for details. 
(Since the first non-blank character of the first line is a `#`,
the line will be treated as a comment. 
This is an important and often-overlooked aspect of how shebangs work.)

Unrelated to the body of your question —
you should always quote your shell variable references
(e.g., `"$i"` and `"$PBS_O_WORKDIR"`)
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing;
see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace
or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216) and [Security implications
of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216). 
And you don’t need to use `"$PWD"` as often as you think you do —
it’s usually good enough to use **`.`**. 
And (IMNSHO) it helps readability to use spaces wherever you can. 
So I suggest that you modify your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}
do
        cd "conf$i"
        cp ../nvt.mdp .
        cp ../topol.top .
        grompp -v -f nvt.mdp -c conf$i.gro -p topol.top -o "conf_nvt$i.tpr" >> nvt.log
        cat <<- KHIK >> "run_nvt$i.pbs"
        #!/bin/bash
        #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
        #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
        #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
        #PBS -q blaze
        #PBS -j oe
        #PBS -V
        cd "\$PBS_O_WORKDIR"
        export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
        /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm "conf_nvt$i"
        KHIK
        cd ..
done
```

Note the spaces before and after the `<<-`, and the additional quotes.

A style choice that I like is to indent here documents:

```
           ︙
        grompp -v -f nvt.mdp -c conf$i.gro -p topol.top -o "conf_nvt$i.tpr" >> nvt.log
        cat <<- KHIK >> "run_nvt$i.pbs"
                #!/bin/bash
                #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16
                #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
                #PBS -N GROMACS:TAUAT_P
                #PBS -q blaze
                #PBS -j oe
                #PBS -V
                cd "\$PBS_O_WORKDIR"
                export I_MPI_DEVICE=rdma
                /home/apps/ics/impi/latest/bin64/mpiexec.hydra /home/braf/md/gromacs-4.5.6/bin/mdrun_mpi -deffnm "conf_nvt$i"
        KHIK
        cd ..
           ︙
```

I believe that it makes it easier to skim-read the script,
and see which lines are commands that are being executed now,
and which ones are data
(e.g., input to a script, where they may be executed later).

P.S. Don’t you want to do `chmod +x "run_nvt$i.pbs"` at some point?
__________
<sup>1</sup> Today I learned that there *are* programs
called [`dog`](https://man.cx/dog) and [`unicorn`](https://man.cx/unicorn).